# locate specific char and replace it in Java

Tags: java, android

I am getting around a hundred url strings from my JSON. Example:

```
media.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1625646_**b.jpg**
media.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_189765_**b.jpg**
media.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_162_**b.jpg**
media.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_532535677_**b.jpg**
media.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1612452_**b.jpg**
media.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_10976562**_b.jpg**
```

As you see, the only common thing in these urls is the end **"b.jpg"**

How can I replace the character **b** with other character?

I have tried with this method:

```
public String changeCharInPosition(int position, char ch, String str){

    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    charArray[position] = ch;
    return new String(charArray);
}
```

Here is when I call it:

```
hs.thumbNailUrl = changeCharInPosition(65, 'l',hs.thumbNailUrl);
```

But the position of **b** always changes, so this method is inefficient.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the urls?

Answer (score 1):

If you are always only going to have one char of that value you can just use .replace() to replace that character.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String x = new String("amedia.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1625646_**b.jpg**");
    x = x.replace('b', 'y');
}
```

**Output**

amedia.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1625646_**y.jpg**

Now if you are trying to replace based off of the index of the character you could use StringBuilder and find the location of b by using substring and finding the location of b by subtracting the the number of chars after b from the total length.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder("amedia.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1625646_**b.jpg**");
    x.setCharAt(x.length() - 7, 'y');
}
```

**Output**

amedia.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1625646_**y.jpg**

**EDIT**

Third option:

Here we are replacing the char at the last index of 'b'.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String x = new String("amedia.life.com/homes/1000000/10000/6500/6404/6404_1625646_**b.jpg**");
    x = x.replace(x.charAt(x.lastIndexOf('b')), 'y');
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Now obviously you can loop through and use a new character for each string.

Comment: Thanks but my app closed when i tried the first way  hs.thumbNailUrl = hs.thumbNailUrl.replace('b','l');

Comment: Its crash because there is url's with more then one "B", i need a way to replace only the last "B"

Comment: @Eli either use option 2 or see my edit for option 3. Option 3 might work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your call to `changeCharInPosition` from

```
hs.thumbNailUrl = changeCharInPosition(65, 'l', hs.thumbNailUrl);
```

to

```
hs.thumbNailUrl = changeCharInPosition(hs.thumbNailUrl.indexOf("b.jpg"),
                                       'l', hs.thumbNailUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.lastIndexOf(String) in order to find the last occurrence of one String inside another.

e.g.

```
private String replace(String url, String thumnailUri){
    String toReplace = "**b.jpg**";
    int lastBIndex = url.lastIndexOf(toReplace);
    return url.substring(0, lastBIndex) + thumnailUri;
}
```

You could also use String.replace(String, String) e.g.

```
url.replace("**b.jpg**", hs.thumnailUri);
```